# How to deconstruct union with "with"?

Tags: f#, with-statement, discriminated-union

I have some problems to use "with" with a discriminated union:

```
type NaturalPerson = {
    FirstName: string
    LastName: string
}

type CorporateEntity = {
    Name1: string
    Name2: string option
}

type Person = 
    | Natural of NaturalPerson
    | Company of CorporateEntity

let company = Company { Name1 = "Foo Bar AG"; Name2 = Some "Baz" }
```

Now I want to change Name2 to None, but I could not figure out how.
Something like:

```
let company2 = Company { company with Name2 = None }
```

In my "real world example" of course this is nested, otherwise I could use the correct type.

Maybe this isn't possible, because I have to pattern match for an edge case, that can not exist (but the compiler is not smart enough to know).

Comment: What do you want to do if `company` is a `Natural person`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you break it out a bit more it is easier to see the problem. In fact what is probably making this difficult is the naming.

```
let company = Company { Name1 = "Foo Bar AG"; Name2 = Some "Baz" } // Person
let company2 = Company { company with Name2 = None } // Person, but broken because expecting company to be type of CorporateEntity
```

So you are trying to create a `CorporateEntity` with a `Person` type, which are not the same.

This works because the correct type is used.

```
let c1 : CorporateEntity = { Name1 = "Foo Bar AG"; Name2 = Some "Baz" }
let p1 : Person = Company c1
let c2 : CorporateEntity = { c1 with Name2 = None }
let p2 : Person = Company c2
```

I have added the types and changed the name to make the type more apparent.
You could `match` on this...

```
match company with // <- rename company to person so it is clearer
| Natural _ -> company
| Company c -> Company { c with Name2 = None }
```

If you wanted to match in a function you could do it like this:

```
let noCompanyName2 (c:CorporateEntity) = // c:CorporateEntity -> Person
    let { Name1 = n1; Name2 = _ } = c
    let company3 = Company { Name1 = n1; Name2 = None }
    company3
```

Or more concisely:

```
let noCompanyName2 ({ Name1 = n1; Name2 = _ }) = Company { Name1 = n1; Name2 = None }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would do it (I'm assuming that if the variable `company` is a `NaturalPerson` then you want it unchanged):

```
match company with
| Person _ -> company
| Company corpEntity -> Company { corpEntity with Name2 = None }
```